# SAP Gui Script not accessing all data

Tags: python, sap-gui

I have a python program where i am trying to get all the data from a grid in SAP-gui (va05) and put in a pandas df.
It's working except that it only pulls the first 195 rows from the grid.

while i< countRows:

```
    reqn = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").getCellValue(i,"ZZATTN")

    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").contextMenu

    po = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").getCellValue(i,"VBELN")

    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").contextMenu
```

I have tried to access the 200th item and just get blanks.
I'm thinking it is a limitation rather than coding.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

added the following and it worked.

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").firstVisibleRow = i

thinking that it can't read too far past what is visible. this scrolls down the viewable data.